# I had an issue with Devise that I've just fixed, I would like to contribute to the project sending this fix, but how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise

I am new on RoR development and some days ago I found me fighting against a bug that was annoying me. Every time I started my rails server I got the following message :

```
/mypath/config/initializers/devise.rb:219: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
```

And the exact piece of code was :

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if Rails.env.development?
```

Then, I fixed it.

But my question is, I couldn't find any issue on Devise's Github page, neither on their Mailing List, but I would like to contribute sending this fix or even just the issue, what should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Post it on their issue tracker https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues

Comment: Even with that snippet, I'm still getting the same warning.

Comment: Note that is not the fix, It was the buggy code, to fix it you have to verify if OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER really exists

Answer (score 0):

Either submit an issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues or fork the project and offer a pull request: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pulls